# Spring Roo + GWT: is RequestFactory still the way to go if "dual control" is required for every data operation?

Tags: gwt, spring-roo

One requirement in our application is to implement "dual control" for everything, including CRUD operations. 
Just to be clear, "dual control" is a feature that requires a change in the data to be approved by someone other than the change requestor. So when a user make changes to data, it's not directly committed to production tables. I'm aware of several ways to implement this (e.g. staging tables) but thats for other time.

The question, with such requirement, do you think we should follow the standard "data centric" way of generated Roo + GWT (which uses RequestFactory) ?

Or we'll better off implementing our own "command pattern" based framework to support dual control?

I'm inclined toward the latter. My intuition (which based on 3 days play-around with Roo+GWT) says that RequestFactory is not designed with dual control in mind, and we'll hit a wall if we try to force our way in. Would be more than happy to be proven wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at RequestFactory's [`ServiceLayerDecorator`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/server/ServiceLayerDecorator.html)?  It mediates all interaction between the payload processing and your domain objects and code.  As an example, you could override the `getProperty` and `setProperty` methods to read from and write into some kind of "shadow" log that holds pending mutations.

If you need to implement ACLs for objects, methods, or properties, the `loadDomainObject` and `resolveX` methods can be used to control which server-side classes any given request can interact with.

To wire in a custom decorator, you can subclass `RequestFactoryServlet` and call the two-arg constructor.  Alternatively, you can just instantiate a `SimpleRequestProcessor` using the object returned from [`ServiceLayer.create()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/server/ServiceLayer.html#create%28com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator...%29).

Implementation note: all of RequestFactory's default domain-interaction behavior is built using a series of `ServiceLayerDecorators`; check out the GWT source if you want to see example code for building a `ServiceLayerDecorator`.  One thing to note is that if your decorator calls any methods defined in the `ServiceLayer` API, it should use the instance provided by `getTop()`.  `ServiceLayerDecorator` instances are expected to be stateless and reusable, so if you need to maintain state across method calls, consider using `ThreadLocal` variables, similar to `RequestFactoryServlet.getThreadLocalX()`.

Comment: very useful pointer. this seems to be the right direction. i'll take a look and accept your answer if it is indeed suit our need. apparently 3 days is not enough to grasp everything. :)

Answer (score 3):

It really depends what "user experience" you want, and particularly whether you want users to validate "diffs" of what has been changed, or approve the "new version" (snapshot).

If you want diffs, because RequestFactory only sends diffs (i.e. the actual changes the user, or you code, made to the objects) to the server, then intercepting `setProperty` calls as suggested by Bob is certainly one way to do it (to make Bob suggestion a bit clearer: you'd "store" the diff in a static `ThreadLocal` so you can retrieve it from your service call). You could also use "smarter" domain objects, that build an internal diff when their setters are called; the diff would then be accessible for each object on the object itself.

If you want snapshots, then you simply have to implement your services to store the modified objects in "staging tables" or whatever rather than in the "production tables"; and then "move" them to the "production tables" when the "approve" service is called.

One thing that's clear (to me), is that you have to model your services and/or objects around "dual control" and not try to do it within "simple CRUD" operations (i.e. the "save" is not a "save", it's a "send for approval"; and there's a separate "approve" operation).

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but isn't the ThreadLocal going to cause issues (not work) if you are running against a server-farm instead of a single host?

Comment: No. A servlet (unless using Servlets 3.0, and RequestFactoryServlet doesn't) processes a request in a single thread, on a single server. The goal of the ThreadLocal here is just to share things between _disconnected_ parts processing bits of the same HTTP request. It's _not_ about sharing things between requests (which could be dispatched to different servers in a farm).